# Paypal integration in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: paypal, integration, xamarin.forms, payment

Do you know if there is any way to integrate Paypal in my Xamarin.Forms app?

My customer wants to include Paypal in the payment process.

Thanks!

Comment: Note that app stores have rules about receiving payment outside of in-app purchases. Especially Google is kinda strict about it. So read on up on that before making a great effort and then find out that your submission is turned down.

Comment: thank you @GeraldVersluis but that does not reply my question :)

Answer (score 2):

Check this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PayPal.Forms/
and read Wiki here:
https://github.com/AlejandroRuiz/PayPal.Forms

And there are one more: https://components.xamarin.com/view/nsoftware.InPayPal.Indie

Answer (score 0):

There is another option and that is to use BrainTree and integrate PayPal. Currently BrainTree isn't exactly supported on Xamarin.Forms but they provide easy to use GUI called Drop-In UI which allows easy implementation.

This is a bit more complicated than PayPal.Forms but it can integrate with other billing methods too like Credit Cards, Apple Pay and Google.

To implement it you will need to make native bindings of the Android and iOS functions to its C# equivalent (not sure about Windows Phone) and then create dependency services for both Android and iOS calling on those bindings.

You can create your own bindings or find existing ones in the nuget packages. I am currently using bindings created by [NAXAM](https://github.com/NAXAM).